# NativeScript always guarantees space below a TextField even if it''s unnecessary

Tags: ios, nativescript

What I'd like to make is a simple app with a TextField at the bottom (just like chat apps like iMessage, TeleGram, etc.)

The problem is this. When keyboard is hidden, NativeScript makes the bottom inset below the TextField (for home swipe), which is nice. It seems NativeScript automatically fills the background color for it, too.
([screenshot when keyboard is hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9e16H.png))

However, when keyboard shows up, I expected the bottom inset just below the TextField to disappear, since it's not required anymore. However, it seems NativeScript keeps bottom inset below the TextField AND for the native soft keyboard at the same time.([screenshot when keyboard has shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dFCW.png))

This is codes that I used to recreate the problem. (It's in NativeScript-Vue)

```
<template>
    <Page>
        <ActionBar title="Home" />
        <DockLayout class="home-panel">
            <StackLayout dock="bottom" background="#444488">
                <TextField height="50" />
            </StackLayout>
            <Label textWrap="true" text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua." />
        </DockLayout>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {};
        }
    };
</script>

<style scoped>
.home-panel {
   font-size: 20;
}
</style>
```

I've been stuck in this problem for days now. Any help or workaround would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this specific to iPhone X and similar models? Did you try iosOverflowSafeArea?

Comment: Yep iPhone models without notches doesn't have the problem (at least in the simulator). I've set TextField's `iosOverflowSafeArea` to `true` and `false` but there's always a bottom inset below the TextField regarless.